# datatables getting row position after sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables plugin with paging,sorting. There is more than one page of data presented to user. Datatables data is periodically refreshed with ajax json datasource.

I select row from database and after a while value for that row changes,since there is paging because of sorting selected row might slip to other page and become invisible to user unless he scrolls to page where his entry is.

I tried with **fnGetPosition()** but it only shows me position of tr in aaData source.

Question is how to get row position in datatable after sorting so i can switch to appropriate page where selected entry is marked

Comment: Some code and html samples of the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**fnSettings()** has attribute called aiDisplayMaster which contains array of **fnGetPosition()**[0] values, i managed to use that to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

This code will move you to the page with a given row (in my case it's a page with row with class .selectedItem). However, it uses newer API of datatables.

```
function moveToPageWithSelectedItem() {
    var numberOfRows = itemsTable.data().length;
    var rowsOnOnePage = itemsTable.page.len();
    if (rowsOnOnePage < numberOfRows) {
        var selectedNode = itemsTable.row(".selectedItem").node();
        var nodePosition = itemsTable.rows({order: 'current'}).nodes().indexOf(selectedNode);
        var pageNumber = Math.floor(nodePosition / rowsOnOnePage);
        itemsTable.page(pageNumber).draw(false); //move to page with the element
    }
}
```